# Probability concerning permutations of non-distinct objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have four not all distinct objects, say $1,1,2,2$, and I am considering the following two settings of the probability concerning the permutations.  Let $R_i$ be the number of the $i$-th object, $i=1,2,3,4$.

For any permutation $\sigma_4$ of $1,1,2,2$:

(i) Suppose  that
$$
P((R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4)=\sigma_4)=\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6.
$$

(ii) We think of the four elements are distinct, i.e.
$$
P((R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4)=\sigma_4)=4!=24.
$$

Then, after some calculations, I found that the probability distributions of $(R_1,R_2,R_3,R_4)$ under (i) and (ii) are the same. For example,
$$
P(R_1=1)=\frac{1}{2}
$$
in either case. Please correct me if i am wrong, thanks. And, is there any intuitive explanation for this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation 1:**
$P(R_1=1)$ is the proportion of objects which have the label $1$.

**Explanation 2:**

Every indistinguishable permutation on $1,1,2,2$ corresponds to $4$ distinguishable permutations on $1,1,2,2$; to turn an indistinguishable permutation into a distinguishable permutation there is a choice of whether or not to swap the $1$s, and a choice of whether or not to swap the $2$s, which gives us $2\times 2$ options.

So for every indistinguishable permutation which begins with a $1$, there are exactly $4$ distinguishable permutations which begin with a $1$.

**Explanation 3:**

> A group is a set $S$ equipped with a binary operation $*$ such that:
>
> - For any $a,b$ in $S$, $a*b$ is in $S$
> - There exists an element $e$ in $S$ (called the identity element) such that, for any $a,b$ in $S$, $a*e=e*a=a$.
> - For every element $a$ in $S$, there exists an element $a^{-1}$ (called the inverse) such that $aa^{-1}=a^{-1}a=e$

The group of all permutations of $4$ distinguishable objects is denoted by $S_4$. It contains $24$ elements. As an example, if $a$ is the permutation which swaps the first two objects then $a^{-1}=a$ and $aa^-1$ is the 'do nothing' permutation.

Denote the group of (indistinguishable) permutations of $1,1,2,2$ by $H$.

There is a *homomorphism* $\phi$ from $S_4$ to $H$, which is the map from $S_4$ to $H$ which 'forgets' whether or not it swapped the $1$s and 'forgets' whether or not it swapped the $2$s.  The set of elements in $S_4$ which are mapped to the identity permutation in $H$ is called the *kernel* of the homomorphism $\phi$. It contains $4$ elements and is denoted by $\text{ker}\{\phi\}$

> A subgroup $N$ of the group $G$ is a *normal subgroup* if $gng^{-1}$ is in $N$ for any $g$ in $G$ and $n$ in $N$.

> If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$ then the *quotient group* $G_1/N$ is defined as follows: Start with the group $G_1$. If two elements $g_1,g_2$ in $G$ satisfy $g_1n_1=g_2n_2$ for some $n_1,n_2$ in $N$ then declare $g_1$ and $g_2$ to be equal.

> The *first isomorphic theorem* states that, for any surjective homomorphism $\varphi:G_1\rightarrow G_2$, $\text{ker}\{\varphi\}$ is a normal subgroup of $G_1$ and $G_1/\text{ker}\{\varphi\}$ is isomorphic to $G_2$.

The first isomorphism theorem implies that four elements in $S_4$ are mapped to every element of $H$.

$\phi$ maps any permutation in $S_4$ which begins with a $1$ to a permutation in $H$ which begins with a $1$, and it also maps permutations which do not begin with a $1$ to permutations which do not begin with a $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the three explanations